# Adding HTML elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, if I have HTML like this:

```
<div id='div'>
  <a>Link</a>

  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

How can I use JavaScript to add an HTML element where that blank line is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you didn't mention any use of javascript libraries (like jquery, dojo), here's something Pure javascript.

```
var txt = document.createTextNode(" This text was added to the DIV.");
var parent = document.getElementById('div');
parent.insertBefore(txt, parent.lastChild);
```

or

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'mypage.htm');
var parent = document.getElementById('div');
parent.insertAfter(link, parent.firstChild);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('#div')` will be null, you probably meant `document.getElementById('div')`

Comment: This is incorrect.  *insertBefore* is not a global function, it's a method on the *HTMLElement* prototype.  The correct method is `parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, childElement)`.

Comment: `insertAfter` is not an actual function either.

Answer (score 50):

```
node = document.getElementById('YourID');
node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>Sample Div</div>');
```

**Available Options**

> beforebegin,  afterbegin, beforeend, afterend

Comment: This has pretty good browser support, too. If you don't plan to use it on older IE's in combination with tables. http://caniuse.com/#feat=insertadjacenthtml

Comment: Should be the accepted answer nowdays. Full browser support and short as hell.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of dealing with the `<div>`'s children, like other answers, if you know you always want to insert after the `<a>` element, give it an ID, and then you can insert relative to its siblings:

```
<div id="div">
  <a id="div_link">Link</a>

  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

And then insert your new element directly after that element:

```
var el = document.createElement(element_type); // where element_type is the tag name you want to insert
// ... set element properties as necessary

var div = document.getElementById('div');
var div_link = document.getElementById('div_link');
var next_sib = div_link.nextSibling;

if (next_sib)
{
  // if the div_link has another element following it within the link, insert
  // before that following element
  div.insertBefore(el, next_sib);
}
else
{
  // otherwise, the link is the last element in your div,
  // so just append to the end of the div
  div.appendChild(el);
}
```

This will allow you to always guarantee your new element follows the link.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use something like jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('#div a').after("Your html element");
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a nice, built in function for this: after(), at http://api.jquery.com/after/

In your case, you will probably want a selector like this:

```
$('#div a').after('<p>html element to add</p>');
```

The code examples from the link given above also show how to load jQuery if that is new to you.

Answer (score 1):

[`Element#after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) can be used to insert elements directly after a certain HTML element.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector("#div > a").after(
  Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {textContent: 'test', style: 'border: 1px solid'}));
```

```html
<div id='div'>
  <a>Link</a>

  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only adding one element:

```
document.getElementById("div").insertBefore({Element}, document.getElementById("div").children[2]);
```