# .after() jQuery method in native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to write the following jQuery code in native Javascript:

```
$("a[href $= pdf]").after("<img src='images/small_pdf_icon.gif' align='center' />");
```

And here's my HTML :

```
<ul class="navlist" id="navlinks">
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #1</a></li>
    <li><a name="#anchor1">Named Anchor Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #4</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #5</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.html">Link #7</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:joe@joe.com">Email Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
    <li><a href="someurl.pdf">Link #6</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can use `document.querySelectorAll('a')` to get all anchor tags, but how can I write JavaScript code for `.after()` or `.before()` methods?

Please help me to convert the above jQuery code into JavaScript.

Here's the Jquery code which I've done :

http://jsfiddle.net/5dgZV/

And Here's Javascript code but I'm not able to insert image after all the Anchors :

http://jsfiddle.net/REuJP/

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: jQuery is open source, see how it does it.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.after might be a perfect starting point

Comment: Follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425142/adding-html-elements-with-javascript

Comment: You can also use Element.insertAdjacentHTML method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are repeatedly trying to append the same DOM to every `a` tag. If you created a new element for every loop iteration, it should work:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll('a').length;i++){
    var imgSrc=document.createElement("img");
    imgSrc.setAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/YXsJZVe.gif");   
    document.querySelectorAll('a')[i].appendChild(imgSrc);
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/REuJP/22/)

Answer (score -1):

while I am hesitant to show you exactly how to do this you should look into the `DOM` api specifically at the method `insertBefore`. Although you should really do a quick google search before asking questions here on SO, here is a reference to `insertBefore` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore.

`insertAfter` is something you would setup using a custom function. like this

```
   insertAfter(newNode){
      var refNode = document.getElementById("xyz"); 
      refNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, refNode.nextSibling);
   }
```

`newNode` in this case is an actual `DOM` element. which would be created like so: `var newNode = document.createElement("p");`

Change `p` for the type of element you want to make. in your case it would be the `img`. You can then set the appropriate attributes/Properties and then send it to the `insertAfter` above. If you need to specify the refNode add an argument for it like so: `insertAfter(newNode,refNode)`.

A way to use this with jquery would be `insertAfter(newNode,$("#findme"))` just so you have an idea of what is going on, obviously if you add the `refNode` argument remove the declaration from the function body.

Comment: I was marked down because? Considering those are the methods you would use and the api you should be using to do this?

Comment: This answer would probably work better as a comment, as it doesn't really provide a solution, just a prod in the right direction. Unless you're willing to show the OP how to use the methods you have mentioned?

Comment: I've searched every where and also used insertBefore Method in javascript but I need to insert after or before all the ANCHOR TAGS like jquery does, but Javascript only inserting after one Anchor Tag , if I'm looping through anchors to put that .gif image after each anchor then also it's putting at last anchor only.

Comment: @Nomad101 Good for you :)