# How to insert HTML element via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert an image into a div tag with the ID "window":

```
<div id="window">
        <h3 id="score">Score: 0</h3>
        <h3 id="end">End Game</h3>
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="images/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

What my function looks like atm:

```
function spawn1() {
document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = "<img src='images/redtarget.png' style='width:10%'>";
}
```

How can I insert an HTML element without using .innerHTML since it replaces everything within my div tag?

Comment: it's `document.getElementById("window").append('<img src="images/redtarget.png" style="width:10%">')` & you might use `createElement` rather than having the image-element as a string

Comment: @admcfajn are you sure it's `document.getElementById("window").innerHTML.append` ?

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekPandey it's been a long day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding HTML elements with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425142/adding-html-elements-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to attach an image into your div you can do the following:

```
function spawn1() {
    let imageElement = document.createElement('img');
    imageElement.setAttribute('src','images/redtarget.png');
    imageElement.setAttribute('id', 'imageId');   //Use the id for a CSS selector to style it
    let windowDiv = document.getElementById("window");
    windowDiv.appendChild(imageElement);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + myNewStuff;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @IgorF.: Yes, code-only answers are discouraged. But they should still be reviewed as "Looks OK" in the Low Quality Posts queue. Reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate existing html like bellow.

```
function spawn1() {
    document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = document.getElementById("window").innerHTML + "<img src='images/redtarget.png' style='width:10%'>";
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpkquwz0/) link: https://jsfiddle.net/gpkquwz0/

Comment: why don't to store `innerHTML` in  a `var` instead of writing it again and again